# Javascript/JQuery: Variable Undefined After Performing Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the `console.log`, I can see that `this.id` is `undefined` after the Ajax call. I would still like to use the `id` of `.home` after that. I know I can again still perform `$('.home').attr('id')` in the `.done` section but that would be repeating the same code again. Is there a better/more efficient way of calling `this.id` (the `id` of `.home`) inside `.done`? I have placed the JavaScript file at the bottom of the `<body>` tag.

**JQuery**

```
$(".home").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  var sendData = {
        //Some data
      };
  var url = "/home" + this.id;
  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: JSON.stringify(sendData)
  }).done(function(result){
      //This shows undefined.
      console.log(this.id)
  })
});
```

Comment: How do you know that 'this.id' exists at all?  Have you tested it before the url attempts to use it?  I suspect that 'this' in .done is not the same as 'this' when called by the submit method...try console.dir(this) ; in each method to see the contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that `this` behaves little bit [differently](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) than in other languages. You have two options:

Either you can put `id` into variable

```
var id = this.id;
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: JSON.stringify(sendData)
}).done(function(result){
  console.log(id)
})
```

or you can bind `this`

```
var onDone = function(result) {
  console.log(this.id)
}
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: JSON.stringify(sendData)
}).done(onDone.bind(this));
```

this way your `this` will stay the same

Answer (score 2):

You need to store your id before the ajax request like :

```
$(".home").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  var sendData = {};
  var id = this.id;
  var url = "/home" + id;
  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: JSON.stringify(sendData)
  }).done(function(result){
      console.log(id)
  })
});
```